# Can we use WHOSE for things? (or should I use 'that' or 'which'?)

Tags: sentence-construction

> I have changed the net connection to a package that/which cost is $15 per month.

Which relative pronoun is proper to use in such scenarios? Can we use *whose* for abstract or non-living things?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this format? The simplest version would be "I have changed the net connection to a package that costs $15 per month."

Comment: @Catija No, I was just asking that which one would be better in my format

Answer (score 4):

It would be "whose".  You are saying that the package's cost is $15 per month.  That is possessive.  "Which" is to refer to a noun previously mentioned, but "whose" is the possessive pronoun.  As @Catija mentioned in the comments, though, this would sound better:

> I have changed the net connection to a package that [or which] costs $15 per month.

Answer (score 0):

"I have changed the net connection to a package **which costs** $15 per month."

This converts the final clause from the passive to the active, and then uses 'which' correctly, as a way of giving further detail about "the package".

The alternative, "I have changed the net connection to a package **whose cost is** $15 per month." would be highly unusual.  Generally speaking, the possessive "whose" is more often used of people.

This is not exclusively true - e.g. "This is an idea whose time has come" is a common expression.  But generally, I would avoid use of the possessive 'whose' when applied to inanimate objects.