# Alternatives to whose

Tags: word-request, possessives

I've just written on another SE site:

> My problem is that I can't ignore a file whose name I don't know

and I keep wondering whether there's another word for whose in this case. Somehow it sounds overcomplicated to me (I'm not a native in English anyway)

Some other questions such as [Can we use WHOSE for things? (or should I use 'that' or 'which'?)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86581/can-we-use-whose-for-things-or-should-i-use-that-or-which/86616#86616) explains that I can *use* this word but, Could I use another word as an alternative?

Comment: My problem is that I can't ignore a file that I don't know its name

Comment: @Cardinal That's ungrammatical. It would have to be _... ignore a file that I don't know the name of_ with a stranded preposition. Still a relative clause though, and not really an improvement

Comment: @BillJ Why the possessive **its** is wrong here? I am curious to know. I thought the OP asked for a substitution for **whose**.

Comment: @Cardinal: In English, in a relative clause like this, it's wrong to refer back to the topic of the clause with "it" in that way. In some languages one might say the equivalent of "\*Here is the pencil that I broke it" (using "it" to make it clear where "the pencil" relates to the subordinate clause), but this is not grammatical in English (you have to say "Here is the pencil that I broke" - with no "it"). When the topic of the subordinate clause is neither the subject nor object in that clause this can sometimes be difficult to word the sentence well, as in this example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Whose* is absolutely normal there. in writing, and I would use it in speech as well.

Colloquially, you could say "a file [that] I don't know the name of".

Comment: All the responses are great, but I think that this attacks the "overcomplication" of my sentence. Thanks

Comment: Also, "*I can't ignore a file if I **don't know what it's called***",

Comment: Is it really correct here? I thought whose (same as who) can only be used for persons (and file is a thing)? (I'm not a native)

Comment: "a file [that] I don't know the name of" - to be totally correct in the way that infuriated Churchill ;-) you would say 'a file of which I do not know the name' or the (perhaps even stricter) transformation suggested by MadWard

Comment: `a file I don't know the name of` is much better IMO and eliminates a useless use of `that` which is always pleasing because `that` is such useless cruft so often

Comment: No @Arsen, _whose_ means _of which_ as well as _of who_, and can be used for things.

Answer (score 6):

You could use **when**, like this:

> My problem is that I can't ignore a file when I don't know its name.

The emphasis shifts a little – *whose* emphasizes the file, while *when* emphasizes the event. Overall, though, the sentence retains its general meaning.

Comment: @psmears What do you think about this answer? Is it ungrammatical? I just want to learn that. J.R. this is about the comments below the questions!

Comment: You could use "if" or "because" instead of "when". That would emphasize the *reason* why you can't ignore it, rather than the *event* of ignoring it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **of which**, but it gets even more complicated:

> My problem is that I can't ignore a file **the name of which** I don't know.

Or simply rewording with **with**:

> My problem is that I can't ignore a file **with** an unknown name.

Comment: My vote goes to the rewording with **with**.

Comment: Yes, but your 2nd example implies that the file's name is not known to anyone, whereas in the OP's example, the file name is only unknown to the speaker

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was asking for an alternative for `whose` and you provided one. But I agree with you: it gets even more complicated :D. It might be a problem of thinking in Spanish when writing in English!